# Displaying QR code image in a specific div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, qr-code

I succed to convert my QR code to image, but it displayed in a blank page. I want to be displayed in a div. 
Here is my code:

```js
$('#qrBloc').qrcode({width: 200,height: 200, text:"something"});
var canvas = document.querySelector("#qrBloc canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img id ="qrimg" src="'+img+'"/>');
```

```html
<div id="qrBloc">
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need the qrcode as an image? Why isn't canvas enough?

Comment: Because after I want to download it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `document.write`.

Replace that line with

```
$('#qrBloc').append('<img id ="qrimg" src="'+img+'"/>');
```

To also remove the canvas element, you could do either of these :

```
$('#qrBloc').empty().append('<img id ="qrimg" src="'+img+'"/>');

$('#qrBloc').html('<img id ="qrimg" src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Doc https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: This is because like this, you have the canvas element and the image element.

Comment: Yep, so how can I keep only the image

Comment: Good, It's working now. I forgot about **html**. Thank you